# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first1

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is the code for Logcat please help. When i click run these errors apear everytime even though i searched some stuff up.

```
        10-03 16:27:07.114: D/AndroidRuntime(7652): Shutting down VM
10-03 16:27:07.114: W/dalvikvm(7652): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41271930)
10-03 16:27:07.114: E/AndroidRuntime(7652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 16:27:07.114: E/AndroidRuntime(7652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wagr.ftc.cascade_app/wagr.ftc.cascade_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

and this is my actual code

```
package wagr.ftc.cascade_app;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AutonomousFragment autoFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // set action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        autoFrag = new AutonomousFragment();

        FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fT = fM.beginTransaction();
        fT.add(R.id.container,autoFrag );
        fT.commit();

//        //add tabs
//          actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
//                  .setText("General")
//                  .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<AutonomousFragment>(autoFrag,this,AutonomousFragment.class)));
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class AutonomousFragment extends Fragment{

        private NumberPicker rampPicker, ballsGoalPicker;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);
            rampPicker = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.Rolling_Goal_Number_Picker);
            ballsGoalPicker = (NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.Ramp_Rolling_Goals_Number_Picker);

            rampPicker.setMaxValue(3);
            rampPicker.setMinValue(0);
            ballsGoalPicker.setMaxValue(2);
            ballsGoalPicker.setMinValue(0);

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why my app isnt running correctly?
Im new to this and need help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the way you are inflating your view on this line:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);
```

The two most common `inflate()` methods are [`inflate(int, ViewGroup)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) and [`inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)). That third parameter is important- if you set it to true, then the layout that you inflate will be attached to the `ViewGroup` passed as the second parameter. If it is set to false, then the layout inflater will only use the second parameter for giving the new layout a set of `LayoutParams`.

If you use the two argument `inflate()` and pass in a non-null `ViewGroup`, then the inflated View is automatically attached as if you had used the three argument `inflate()` and passed `true` as the third argument.

This is important here because when your `onCreateView()` returns a View, Android will attempt to attach the returned View as the Fragment's layout. However, since you used the two argument method, your inflated layout was already attached to another parent.

Switch that line to the following, and you should be fine.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Comment: Under what circumstances is it desirable for the child view to have a parent view?

Comment: Well, your Views always have a parent. If you are asking when you would want to attach an inflated View to a parent, then there are a few situations.  It is useful when you want to inflate a View and add it to a parent such as a LinearLayout when a ListView or RecyclerView isn't appropriate. it is also useful when creating custom Views and you want to provide a layout for your custom View that has a `<merge>` tag as its root.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the stack trace is incomplete, it would be useful to see the full stack.

Anyway, while I didn't actually tried your code, it is possible you are having this error due to:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);
```

If you navigate to the inflate implementation, it looks something like:

```
/**
 * Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml node. Throws
 * {@link InflateException} if there is an error. *
 * <p>
 * <em><strong>Important</strong></em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;For performance
 * reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files
 * that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to
 * use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime.
 * 
 * @param parser XML dom node containing the description of the view
 *        hierarchy.
 * @param root Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.
 * @return The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied,
 *         this is the root View; otherwise it is the root of the inflated
 *         XML file.
 */
public View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root) {
    return inflate(parser, root, root != null);
}
```

So, if you replace that line by the one below, it might work:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```