# Android ListFragment - onListItemClick start another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Though it seems an easy problem, I've been stuck for quite a few hours. If anyone can help my out providing some code it'd be great. So there it goes my question.

There's a MainActivity which has an ActionBar with two buttons. Each button starts a ListFragment when it's clicked. Then each item of each ListFragment starts another fragment (that's what I'm not able to achieve). Here is the code for the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    DataListFragment.DataListSelectionListener {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // Reference the buttons in the ActionBar
    private Button actionBarData;
    private Button actionBarElu;
    private Button actionBarOptions;

    // Reference the ListFragments
    DataListFragment dataListFragment;
    EluListFragment eluListFragment;

    // Reference the fragments related to the listItems
    SectionTypeFragment sectionTypeFragment;
    SectionDimensionsFragment sectionDimensionsFragment;
    MaterialsFragment materialsFragment;
    ReinforcementFragment reinforcementFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inflate the custom layout for the ActionBar
        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.action_bar,
                null);
        // Set the custom ActionBar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
        // ActionBar Customization with buttons
        final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_2);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

        actionBarData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_data);
        actionBarData.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG, "DATA button clicked.");
                clickActionBarButton(v);

            }
        });
        actionBarElu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_elu);
        actionBarElu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG, "ELU button clicked.");
                clickActionBarButton(v);

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_bar_data) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void clickActionBarButton(View v){

        // Get a reference to the FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        // Begin a new FragmentTransaction
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Create the fragment depending on the button pressed
        if(v == actionBarData){

            // If there is no FeedFragment instance, then create one
            if(sectionTypeFragment == null)
                dataListFragment = new DataListFragment();

            // Replace the main_frame_layout with the sectionTypeFragment
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layoout, dataListFragment);

        }else if(v == actionBarElu){

            // If there is no FeedFragment instance, then create one
            if(sectionTypeFragment == null)
                eluListFragment = new EluListFragment();

            // Replace the main_frame_layout with the sectionTypeFragment
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, eluListFragment);

        }

        // Commit the FragmentTransaction
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    // Called when the user selects an item in the DataListFragment
    public void onDataListSelection(int index){

        // Get a reference to the FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        // Begin a new FragmentTransaction
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        // Add the fragment related to the selected item in the List
        switch (index){
            case 0:

                // If there is no SectionTypeFragment instance, then create one
                if(sectionTypeFragment == null)
                    sectionTypeFragment = new SectionTypeFragment();

                // Replace the main_frame_layout with the sectionTypeFragment
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, sectionTypeFragment);
                // Add this FragmentTransaction to the backstack
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;

            case 1:

            ...

        }

        // Commit the FragmentTransaction
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

Here is the code for one of the ListFragments (DataListFragment):

```
public class DataListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "DataFragment";

    // List items
    private String[] listItems;

    private DataListSelectionListener mListener = null;

    // Callback interface that allows this Fragment to notify the MainActivity when
    // user clicks on a DataList Item
    public interface DataListSelectionListener {
        public void onDataListSelection(int index);
    }

    // Called when the user selects an item from the DataList
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        // Indicates the selected item has been checked
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

        // Inform the MainActivity that an item has been selected
        mListener.onDataListSelection(position);

    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the the items to show in the List from the strings.xml
        listItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data_list_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Here is the exception:

```
03-12 14:39:38.681  29515-29515/com.tari.rcsec E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3459)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3330)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3275)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3251)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:840)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5022)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1032)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is this an IDE error or a runtime exception? If it's an exception can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: @John P, is an runtime error. I updated the question.

Comment: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.** indicates you are trying to add a view (in this case your fragment) to the layout that has been added to either a different layout or view (in this case the .replace) before.

Comment: @BartdeRuijter, Yes, in this example there is a view in the layout inflated by the fragment. My idea was to add a layout, no matter what's inside it, inflated by the called fragment, isn't it possible? How could it be solved?

Comment: Hmmm, could you try replacing "final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.action_bar,
                null);", with "final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.action_bar,
                null, false);"? It's mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186601/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil) in an answer explaining why it's important to use the method which takes a 3rd parameter, the boolean.

Comment: @BartdeRuijter, I added the third parameter to the mentioned line of code, but the problem persists, it's still not possible to display the new fragment when an item of the ListFragment is clicked.

Comment: @BartdeRuijter, got it! I just added the third parameter you mentioned to the inflater in the class for the fragment that I wanted to display, and now it's working! Thanks!!

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could be of help ^^